# CodeIgniter sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am new to Codeigniter and I am having a problem with sessions;
Either a session is starting even when the user does not log in successfully.
Or 
The user logs in successfully but when I navigate the site the session starts again dropping the user information and starting a new session in my database.

I am completely lost any help greatly appreciated.

**site.php - Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['title']= "Welcome Learn Guitar Online";
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data);
}

public function form()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['title']= "Login";
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('form',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data);
}
    public function login()
{
    $loginEmail=$this->input->post('loginEmail');
    $loginPassword=$this->input->post('loginPassword');

    $result=$this->user_model->login($loginEmail,$loginPassword);
    if($result) $this->myaccount();
    else        $this->form();
}
}
```

**user_model.php - Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
function login($email,$password)
{
$password = sha1($password);

    $this->db->where("Email",$email);
    $this->db->where("Password",$password);

    $query=$this->db->get("members");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                    'user_id'       => $rows->Id,
                    'user_name'     => $rows->First_Name,
                    'user_email'    => $rows->Email,
                    'logged_in'     => TRUE,
               );
        }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return true;            
    }
    return false;
 }
public function add_user()
{
    $data=array(
        'username'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email_address'),
        'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );
    $this->db->insert('user',$data);
}
}
?>
```

**header.php** - On top of every page on application

```
<?php
$sid = $this->session->all_userdata();

if($sid) {
print_r($this->session->userdata); ;
} else {
session_start();
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/css/style.css"; ?>"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/css/skeleton.css"; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/css/layout.css"; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/css/base.css"; ?>" />

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"; ?>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/script.js"; ?>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"; ?>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"; ?>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"; ?>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/comment.js"; ?>"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are using session_start(); in your view. i cant see that has a use here.

to learn about session library use this link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

`load->library('session');` in your model constructor or set `session class` to `autoload`.

Read CI doc it will help you.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To retrive value from session to check wheather the user is logged in or not, use function link this

```
public function verify_login(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!=TRUE){
            redirect('site');
        }
    }
```

Try calling this in `construct` like this

```
$this->verify_login();
```

so when the page loads, it checks for this 1st when that controller is called

instead of loading `library` & `helper` in every function, i suggest you to use `autoload.php` in config folder

can you try changing the model login function to this

```
public function login(){

    $this->db->where('Email',$this->input->post('loginEmail'));
    $this->db->where('Password',sha1($this->input->post('loginPassword')));
    $query=$this->db->get("members");
    if($query->num_rows == 1){
        foreach ($query->result() as $rows){
            $newdata = array(
                'user_id'       => $rows->Id,
                'user_name'     => $rows->First_Name,
                'user_email'    => $rows->Email,
                'logged_in'     => TRUE
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

and your controller login function to this

```
public function login(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('loginEmail','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('loginPassword','Password','trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            //Do what you have to do if validation failed
    } else {
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $result=$this->User_model->login();

        if($result){
            $this->myaccount();
        } else {
            $this->form();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have removed the library and helper as i was simply repeating myself. but the problem is that there is always a  session ongoing, the application seems to start up a new one everytime i change page, i have removed the session_start() from the header but a new sesison still keeps getting started

Comment: have you made a the verify_login() as i mentioned in my answer in your controller & called it like this $this->verify_login(); in your construct ?

Comment: can you change your controller & model login function to what i have given in my answer & see

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if user is logged in or not I would suggest you to use a [pre_controller](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) hook.

And there is some authenticate plugin if you interest:

http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/

http://community-auth.com/

http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/

If codeigniter session class still stores session data directly inside the cookie, and this make you feel uncomfortable you can use [db session class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/DB-Session)